# Filter Data between two number Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, django-models

How can I filter my model obj in range of numbers some thing like

```
Item.objects.filter(4500< price < 7500)
```

I try `for` loop but its too slow and take lots of sources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use range filter

`Item.objects.filter(price__range=(4500, 7500))`

For better understanding check the ref link : - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#range

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `gt` and `lt`.

```
Item.objects.filter(price__gt=4500, price__lt=7500)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the model range to achieve that;

`Model.objects.filter(price__range=[frm, to])`

This should solve what you want to do.